# Does ASP.NET WebMethod request count for session time?

Tags: asp.net, session, asmx, webmethod

I have an ASP.NET application which loads a page and then does all of the work by WebMethods. So for a long time the user does not refresh the page. I think after a while the session hits the timeout and session variables are cleared, because there is at least one WebMethod request at every N minutes (N is less than Session.TimeOut). Is that true? Is there a way to change this behaviour without increasing the TimeOut value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this information [over here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t645068-static-page-methods-and-session-timeouts.html):

> Async postbacks will not keep session alive unless you are using
> cookieless sessions. If you are using cookie based sessions (the
> default), then the timeout is in the cookie. Ajax calls can not update
> this cookie in the browser. As the session timeout logic requires
> sending a new cookie and getting back on redirect, the ajax calls fail
> to do this.
>
> You could switch to sessionless for ajax calls (good performance idea) or go to cookieless sessions

Comment: "As the session timeout logic requires sending a new cookie", then how does it access to session information in webmethods?

Comment: The session information is stored on the server as well, but the cookie timeout can't be updated through Ajax calls.

Comment: For example, you can store the information in the database. Here's more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx

Comment: @DennisTraub, how is session information distinguished on the server if there is no cookie in the webmethod call? i am a bit frustrated...

Comment: actually the cookie is sent with the webmethod (checked in chrome console), but timeout is not updated apperaently, ok..